# Can I use BottomNavigation with components?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to display a bottom navigation, in which the TabContent comes from components. Now, with the following code I can't get the tab content to show, and I don't get any errors.

**PageContainer.vue:**

```
<template>
   <BottomNavigation selectedIndex="1" class="tab__container" @loaded="loaded">
     <TabStrip>
       <TabStripItem class="tab">
         <Label :text="text.groups" />
       </TabStripItem>

       <TabStripItem class="tab">
         <Label :text="text.mail" />
       </TabStripItem>
     </TabStrip>

     <TabContentItem>
       <GroupsScreen />
     </TabContentItem>

     <TabContentItem>
       <MailScreen />
     </TabContentItem>
   </BottomNavigation>
 </template>

<script >
   import GroupsScreen from './GroupsScreen';
   import MailScreen from './MailScreen';

   export default {
     components: {
       GroupsScreen,
       MailScreen,
     },

     data() {
       return {
           text: {
             groups: 'Groepen',
             mail: 'Berichten',
           },
       }
     },
   }
</script>
```

**GroupsScreen.vue:**

```
<template>
   <Frame @loaded="loaded">
       <ActionBar :title="text.groups" />
       <StackLayout class="page">
         <Label v-if="groupsLoading" text="Loading"></Label>
       </StackLayout>
   </Frame>
 </template>
```

Is this even possible, or am I trying to do something that should be done in another way?

Comment: Can you share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Yes: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=besmP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hierarchy is always,

1. **Frame**
2. **Page**
3. **Content** (Layouts, ScrollView etc.,)

A Frame can only host a Page, it can not directly host Content. You need Frame only if you want to navigate within that particular container.

So your primary issue was not wrapping your **BottomNavigation** with a **Page** element.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=besmP1&v=2)